# Deleting a node when it stops being referenced by others

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Say I have a db with the following structure:

```
root:
  bananas:
    banana_a: (potato_1)
    banana_b: (potato_1)
    ...

  potatos:
    potato_1: (...)
    potato_2: (...)
    ...
```

i.e. - `banana_a` and `banana_b` are referencing `potato_1` (saving his unique identifier).

In my app it is possible that a banana would stop referencing a potato.
When there are no bananas left pointing to a potato, it would be deleted to save storage.

I would prefer it if the deletion of the potato would be initiated **by the DB itself (guided by a rule)**, instead of being ordered by the client. 
The reason is I don't want to allow evil users to edit my JS & prevent it from happening.

I don't have any idea how to write such a rule -
A `.validate` rule cannot dispose existing data, and therefore is useless in this situation.

Therefore I requests the assistance of you old wise programmers, with working out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase security rules can allow/disallow read/write operations. They cannot trigger auxiliary reads or writes based on a condition that you specify.

You will have to implement this in your application code. A quite common way to make this easy is by not only storing the reference from a banana to its potato, but also storing the references for each potato to its bananas.

```
potatos:
    potato_1:
        bananas:
            banana_a
            banana_b
    potato_2: (...)
```

That way when you remove the last banana from a potato, you can easily see that the potato can be removed too.

Comment: If my client is talking directly to firebase (the entire idea), then I cannot split the removal to two commands. Some a-holes may find it funny to delete one of the lines, and cause an isolated node which can only be removed manually...  

frankly, firebase's limited syntax and rule set make it irrelevant to most application. You give up either functionality or security to make a non-novice application.